# Reporting: using bayesian and frequentist statistics interchangeably in a study

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, reporting

What would you expect to read in a work's "data analysis" or "statistics" section if this used Bayesian and frequentist methods interchangeably?

I used Bayesian regression, since it's posterior allowed me to do advanced plotting (showed the results of multiple models in one plot). However, for survival analysis, I used frequentist methods (my limited understanding is that Cox models are not that ready in Bayesian?).

Comment: Will you analyze the same questions via both approaches or will you use Frequentism for some and Bayesism for other problems? In the latter case the obvious answer is "I want to read an explanation, why you opted for which in each case". Otherwise this question is prone for opinion-based answers, which are off topic here. So maybe you could go into some more detail what exactly you mean.

Comment: Thanks! I added some detail into the initial post.